# Iterate through, and change all form objects

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a Windows forms application with 6 'Cards'. 'Card' is a class I derived from System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.
I added a member called 'id'.

Is there a way to iterate though all objects of the type 'Card' and change the value of 'id'?

[image: Screenshot]

The class definition is below.

```
    public class Card : System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap Back = MemoryGame.Properties.Resources.MG_back;

        byte id = 0;

        public Card()
        {

            this.Image = Back;

            this.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

         }

        public void Flip(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
        {

            if (this.Image == Back)
            {
                this.Image = bitmap;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Image = Back;
            }
        }

        public int GetId()
        {
            return this.id;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is ID really inaccessible or you just wrote it here like that?

Comment: It was inaccessible and I changed it now. An oversight on my part, but that wasn't what was holding me back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the `Controls` collection, e.g.:

```
int counter = 0;
foreach(var card in this.Controls.OfType<Card>())
{
    card.Id = ++counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the parentcontrols "Controls" property. Then you can check, whether the current control is of your type Card.

```
foreach(var control in parentControl.Controls)
{
    if(control is Card c)
    {
        c.Id = 0 /*Some new value*/
    }
}
```

EDIT: Type pattern used in this example is available starting with C# 7.0